# Check runtime on hue bulbs?

Tags: philips-hue

Are there any way to check how many hours a philips hue bulb have been used? First use, and number of cycles? Would think this is recorded somehow.

I need to check a set I bought as new, but I suspect it's been used :) also it would be interesting to get se stats from the bulbs.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get that information from the bulb or the hub. Hue lights haven't been around that long and they last a long time. Don't worry, just enjoy your bulbs.